# Convolving using Integrate function

Tags: convolution

Convolving two UnitBox using the Convolve function gives accurate results as fig.1). However, when I try using Integrate function according to the document, the results are different as fig2. What should I fix? (※The document I refer is as below;)
[image]

Fig.1) Convolve function used, resulting accurate result

[image]

```
g1 = Plot[UnitBox[x - 1/2], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   Filling -> Axis];
g2 = Plot[
   Convolve[UnitBox[x - 1/2], UnitBox[x - 1/2], x, y], {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[{g1, g2}]
```

Fig.2) My convolution code using Integrate function

[image]

```
g3 = Plot[
   Integrate[ 
    UnitBox[x - 1/2]  UnitBox[y - x + 1/2], {x, 0, 5}], {y, -3, 3}, (*Where should I fix?*)
   PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[{g1, g3}]
```

Comment: I think you want `Integrate[UnitBox[x - 1/2] UnitBox[y - x - 1/2], {x, 0 - 5, 5}]`.

Comment: As you mentioned, if I integrate the product of UnitBox[x - 1/2] and UnitBox[y - x - 1/2], the desired triangle appears. However, as far as I know, looking at the definition of convolution, the sum of the arguments of the two functions should be y. I thought it should be UnitBox[x - 1/2] UnitBox[y - x + 1/2], but when I integrate the product, the wrong triangle came out. Maybe I misunderstood the definition. Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: If `f[x] == UnitBox[x - 1/2]`, then `f[y - x] == UnitBox[(y - x) - 1/2]` -- is how I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = UnitBox[x - 1/2];
g = UnitBox[x - 1/2];
Convolve[f, g, x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
Integrate[f*(g /. x -> (y - x)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same thing.

Answer (score 4):

As an example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
f[x_] := UnitBox[x - 1/2];
g[x_] := UnitBox[x/2];

h[x_] := Convolve[f[τ], g[τ], τ, x]

k[x_] := Integrate[
  f[τ] g[x - τ], {τ, -∞, ∞}]

Plot[#, {x, -4, 4}
     , PlotStyle -> RandomColor[]
     , Exclusions -> None
     , PlotRange -> All
     ] & /@ {f[x], g[x], h[x], k[x]} // 
  Partition[#, 2] & // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

---

In traditional notation:

```
HoldForm@Integrate[
   f[τ] g[x - τ], {τ, -∞, ∞}] // TeXForm
```

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(\tau ) g(x-\tau ) \, d\tau$